# How to check whether particular UIViewController exists or not in app/project

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a bigger project and I just want to check whether a particular `UIViewController` exists or not inside my Project.

Is there any way to get array of all `UIViewController` or any way to check if a particular `UIViewController` Class exists or not?

Please respond asap and thanks a lot.

Comment: you can search that view controller in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode, search in project using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, and search for

`UIViewController {` or `UIViewController{`

Will give you a list of all the View Controllers

Comment: Hi I just want to get array of UIViewControllers programetically in iOS Shift.

Comment: I want to check it programetically that whether particular UIViewController exists or not.

Comment: Do you know it's name?

Comment: Yes I know the name of UIViewController but I have to check whether it exists or not. There is some logical modular issue I am facing. Perhaps, you are going in same direction in which I am trapped and thanks a lot.

Comment: And you can't use the search to find the name?

Comment: Let me describe you whole instance.
Let us suppose,there are total 50 view controllers and I have to check whether a particular view controller exists or not.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to export array. You can use XCode to search for view controllers, and get the list (not array) of all existing view controllers. If you know the name of the specific view controller, you can search for it specifically. Are we on the same page?